# React native props declaration confusion

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have came across this SendBird With React-Native chatting app and i am studying the code structure of it. The following line of codes is causing me confusion:

Function.js

```
export const sbAdjustMessageList = (list) => {
return list.map((message, i) => {
    message['time'] = sbUnixTimestampToDate(message.createdAt);
    message['readCount'] = 0;
    if (message.isUserMessage() || message.isFileMessage()) {
        message['isUser'] = (message.sender.userId === SendBird.getInstance().getCurrentUserId());
    } else {
        message['isUser'] = false;
    }
    if (message.sender) {
        message.sender['isShow'] = true;
        if(!message.sender.profileUrl) {
            message.sender.profileUrl = 'default-image';
        }
    }

    if (i < list.length - 1) {
        let prevMessage = list[i + 1];
        if (message.isUserMessage() || message.isFileMessage()) {
            if (prevMessage.isUserMessage() || prevMessage.isFileMessage()) {
                if (prevMessage.sender.userId === message.sender.userId) {
                    message.sender.isShow = false;  
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return message
});
```

}

Main.js

```
_renderFileMessageItem = rowData => {
    const message = rowData.item;
    if (message.isUserMessage()) {
      return <TextItem isUser={message.isUser} message={message.message} />;
    } else if (sbIsImageMessage(message)) {
      return <ImageItem isUser={message.isUser} message={message.url.replace("http://", "https://")} />;
    } else {
      return <FileItem isUser={message.isUser} message={message.name} />;
    }
  };
```

In Function.js, the is this declaration of `message['isUser']` then it is exported to Main.js to be used. However in Main.js, `isUser` becomes a props to the imported component. Also, there is no initiation of `isUser` in constructor class.

My question is what does `message['isUser']` here means? Is it a javascript thing or a redux features (The sample app uses redux and react-redux)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, with the given code, it can be inferred that the function `sbAdjustMessageList`  takes a list i.e. an `array` of messages and formats all the messages inside it and returns the `array of formatted messages` while the `isUser` being a key in each message.

However in Main.js, `_renderFileMessageItem` is a kind of item renderer for a `ListView` and each item rendering receives a message. Its is quite clear that the rowData is having a message item inside it and this message is one of the messages from the array which the `sbAdjustMessageList` function returned (as this array must have been provided to the ListView).

Coming to `isUser` being a prop for TextItem, its `JSX`, there is no necessity to provide prop declaration to the components while constructing.Although its always better to write quality code and declare all your prop and types with `PropTypes`

and `message['isUser']` is just `javascript`'s way of manipulating object properties.